# Why did my 2017 12” MB go into kernel panic (page fault)?

Tags: macos, hardware, kernel-panic

I was just browsing using safari, had word, notes, chrome and maybe some other light apps open in the background but nothing heavy. Suddenly my mac shutdown and restarted with the "restarted because of a problem" message. I've definitely put this macbook into much more stress so I'm lost. It's a two year old 12 inch Macbook. I just booted pressing D and the report says No problems were found, code ADP0000.

```
The crash report is as follows; I don't know how to interpret it. I’m really worried.

   panic(cpu 0 caller 0xffffff800824aa3a): Kernel trap at 0xffffff7f8b0cfbf4, type 14=page fault, registers:
CR0: 0x000000008001003b, CR2: 0x0000000000000008, CR3: 0x0000000256d0015c, CR4: 0x00000000003626e0
RAX: 0x0000000000000002, RBX: 0xffffff91555f0038, RCX: 0x0000000040014000, RDX: 0x0000000040014000
RSP: 0xffffff914d2838f0, RBP: 0xffffff914d283940, RSI: 0xffffff8032977b08, RDI: 0xffffff803151a000
R8:  0xffffff804beafa40, R9:  0x0000000000000080, R10: 0xffffff914ae4d030, R11: 0x0000000000000000
R12: 0x0000000000000004, R13: 0x0000000000000000, R14: 0xffffff8032976e50, R15: 0xffffff8032976800
RFL: 0x0000000000010206, RIP: 0xffffff7f8b0cfbf4, CS:  0x0000000000000008, SS:  0x0000000000000000
Fault CR2: 0x0000000000000008, Error code: 0x0000000000000002, Fault CPU: 0x0, PL: 0, VF: 0

Backtrace (CPU 0), Frame : Return Address
0xffffff914d283350 : 0xffffff800811f5cd 
0xffffff914d2833a0 : 0xffffff800

8258b05 
0xffffff914d2833e0 : 0xffffff800824a68e 
0xffffff914d283430 : 0xffffff80080c5a40 
0xffffff914d283450 : 0xffffff800811ec97 
0xffffff914d283550 : 0xffffff800811f087 
0xffffff914d2835a0 : 0xffffff80088c27cc 
0xffffff914d283610 : 0xffffff800824aa3a 
0xffffff914d283790 : 0xffffff800824a738 
0xffffff914d2837e0 : 0xffffff80080c5a40 
0xffffff914d283800 : 0xffffff7f8b0cfbf4 
0xffffff914d283940 : 0xffffff7f8b0cef3f 
0xffffff914d2839a0 : 0xffffff7f8afe251e 
0xffffff914d2839e0 : 0xffffff7f8afe2a4f 
0xffffff914d283a10 : 0xffffff7f8b0cf3de 
0xffffff914d283a40 : 0xffffff7f8afe000b 
0xffffff914d283ac0 : 0xffffff800885695e 
0xffffff914d283b10 : 0xffffff8008854be7 
0xffffff914d283b60 : 0xffffff800885dcb3 
0xffffff914d283ca0 : 0xffffff80082082b2 
0xffffff914d283db0 : 0xffffff8008125328 
0xffffff914d283e10 : 0xffffff80080fbcc5 
0xffffff914d283e70 : 0xffffff8008112aa2 
0xffffff914d283f00 : 0xffffff8008230d05 
0xffffff914d283fa0 : 0xffffff80080c6226 
  Kernel Extensions in backtrace:
     com.apple.iokit.IOAcceleratorFamily2(438.5.4)[D695D9DA-7C20-35D6-910F-E7A332A0F515]@0xffffff7f8afd9000->0xffffff7f8b09dfff
        dependency: com.apple.driver.AppleMobileFileIntegrity(1.0.5)[E35D090D-DB9E-3DD0-9723-651FA730AA13]@0xffffff7f891e2000
        dependency: com.apple.iokit.IOPCIFamily(2.9)[BE052F4D-9B80-3FCD-B36D-BACB7DEE0DF2]@0xffffff7f88b31000
        dependency: com.apple.iokit.IOSurface(269.11)[F1E7389D-2807-3C5D-8A7F-5422542E867F]@0xffffff7f8961f000
        dependency: com.apple.iokit.IOGraphicsFamily(576.1)[B1C0006F-E1F5-37D9-9548-5F918E92B422]@0xffffff7f89535000
        dependency: com.apple.iokit.IOReportFamily(47)[1FB49168-0280-3F04-A99A-F830C915E994]@0xffffff7f88f11000
     com.apple.driver.AppleIntelKBLGraphics(14.0.6)[E09E2681-5119-37A7-9975-B87BC4E1AA8F]@0xffffff7f8b0b2000->0xffffff7f8b1a7fff
        dependency: com.apple.iokit.IOPCIFamily(2.9)[BE052F4D-9B80-3FCD-B36D-BACB7DEE0DF2]@0xffffff7f88b31000
        dependency: com.apple.iokit.IOSurface(269.11)[F1E7389D-2807-3C5D-8A7F-5422542E867F]@0xffffff7f8961f000
        dependency: com.apple.iokit.IOGraphicsFamily(576.1)[B1C0006F-E1F5-37D9-9548-5F918E92B422]@0xffffff7f89535000
        dependency: com.apple.iokit.IOAcceleratorFamily2(438.5.4)[D695D9DA-7C20-35D6-910F-E7A332A0F515]@0xffffff7f8afd9000

BSD process name corresponding to current thread: com.apple.photos

Mac OS version:
19F101

Kernel version:
Darwin Kernel Version 19.5.0: Tue May 26 20:41:44 PDT 2020; root:xnu-6153.121.2~2/RELEASE_X86_64
Kernel UUID: 54F1A78D-6F41-32BD-BFED-4381F9F6E2EF
Kernel slide:     0x0000000007e00000
Kernel text base: 0xffffff8008000000
__HIB  text base: 0xffffff8007f00000
System model name: MacBook10,1 (Mac-EE2EBD4B90B839A8)
System shutdown begun: NO
Panic diags file available: YES (0x0)

System uptime in nanoseconds: 25359580732118
last loaded kext at 22180958337014: >!AXsanScheme   3 (addr 0xffffff7f8bd8a000, size 32768)
last unloaded kext at 433015797039: >usb.!UHostPacketFilter 1.0 (addr 0xffffff7f8988e000, size 24576)
loaded kexts:
org.virtualbox.kext.VBoxNetAdp  6.1.4
org.virtualbox.kext.VBoxNetFlt  6.1.4
org.virtualbox.kext.VBoxUSB 6.1.4
org.virtualbox.kext.VBoxDrv 6.1.4
@fileutil   20.036.15
>AudioAUUC  1.70
>AGPM   111.4.4
>!APlatformEnabler  2.7.0d0
>X86PlatformShim    1.0.0
@filesystems.autofs 3.0
>!AHDA  283.15
>!AUpstreamUserClient   3.6.8
>!AGraphicsDevicePolicy 5.2.4
@AGDCPluginDisplayMetrics   5.2.4
>!AHV   1
|IOUserEthernet 1.0.1
|IO!BSerialManager  7.0.5f6
>!ABacklight    180.3
>pmtelemetry    1
>!A!IPCHPMC 2.0.1
>!ASMCLMU   212
>!AMCCSControl  1.14
@Dont_Steal_Mac_OS_X    7.0.0
>!A!IKBLGraphics    14.0.6
>eficheck   1
>!A!ISlowAdaptiveClocking   4.0.0
>!ACameraInterface  7.6.0
>!A!IKBLGraphicsFramebuffer 14.0.6
@filesystems.apfs   1412.120.2
>!AVirtIO   1.0
@filesystems.hfs.kext   522.100.5
@!AFSCompression.!AFSCompressionTypeDataless    1.0.0d1
@BootCache  40
@!AFSCompression.!AFSCompressionTypeZlib    1.0.0
>!ATopCaseHIDEventDriver    3430.1
>AirPort.BrcmNIC    1400.1.1
@private.KextAudit  1.0
>!ASmartBatteryManager  161.0.0
>!AACPIButtons  6.1
>!ARTC  2.0
>!ASMBIOS   2.1
>!AACPIEC   6.1
>!AAPIC 1.7
$!AImage4   1
@nke.applicationfirewall    303
$TMSafetyNet    8
@!ASystemPolicy 2.0.0
|EndpointSecurity   1
>!AXsanScheme   3
|IOUSBUserClient    900.4.2
@kext.triggers  1.0
>DspFuncLib 283.15
@kext.OSvKernDSPLib 529
>!AGraphicsControl  5.2.4
|IOAVB!F    850.1
>!ASSE  1.0
>!ABacklightExpert  1.1.0
>!AHDA!C    283.15
|IOHDA!F    283.15
>!ASMBus!C  1.0.18d1
|IO!BHost!CUARTTransport    7.0.5f6
|IO!BHost!CTransport    7.0.5f6
@!AGPUWrangler  5.2.4
|IONDRVSupport  576.1
|IOSlowAdaptiveClocking!F   1.0.0
>X86PlatformPlugin  1.0.0
>IOPlatformPlugin!F 6.0.0d8
@!AGraphicsDeviceControl    5.2.4
|IOAccelerator!F2   438.5.4
|IOGraphics!F   576.1
>!A!ILpssUARTv1 3.0.60
>!A!ILpssUARTCommon 3.0.60
>!AOnboardSerial    1.0
@plugin.IOgPTPPlugin    840.3
|IOEthernetAVB!C    1.1.0
|IOAudio!F  300.2
@vecLib.kext    1.2.0
|IOSerial!F 11
|IOSurface  269.11
@filesystems.hfs.encodings.kext 1
>!AActuatorDriver   3440.1
>!AHIDKeyboard  209
>!AHS!BDriver   3430.1
>IO!BHIDDriver  7.0.5f6
|IO!B!F 7.0.5f6
|IO!BPacketLogger   7.0.5f6
>!AMultitouchDriver 3440.1
>!AInputDeviceSupport   3440.8
>!AHSSPIHIDDriver   59
>!AHSSPISupport 59
|IO80211!F  1200.12.2b1
>mDNSOffloadUserClient  1.0.1b8
>corecapture    1.0.4
|IOSkywalk!F    1
>!A!ILpssSpi!C  3.0.60
|IONVMe!F   2.1.0
>!AHPM  3.4.4
|IOThunderbolt!F    7.6.1
>!A!ILpssI2C!C  3.0.60
>!A!ILpssDmac   3.0.60
>!A!ILpssGspi   3.0.60
>!A!ILpssI2C    3.0.60
>usb.!UXHCIPCI  1.2
>usb.!UXHCI 1.2
|IOUSB!F    900.4.2
>!AEFINVRAM 2.1
>!AEFIRuntime   2.1
|IOSMBus!F  1.1
|IOHID!F    2.0.0
$quarantine 4
$sandbox    300.0
@kext.!AMatch   1.0.0d1
>DiskImages 493.0.0
>!AFDEKeyStore  28.30
>!AEffaceable!S 1.0
>!AKeyStore 2
>!UTDM  489.120.1
|IOSCSIBlockCommandsDevice  422.120.3
>!ACredentialManager    1.0
>KernelRelayHost    1
>!ASEPManager   1.0.1
>IOSlaveProcessor   1
|IOUSBMass!SDriver  157.121.1
|IOSCSIArchitectureModel!F  422.120.3
|IO!S!F 2.1
|IOUSBHost!F    1.2
>!UHostMergeProperties  1.2
>usb.!UCommon   1.0
>!ABusPower!C   1.0
|CoreAnalytics!F    1
>!AMobileFileIntegrity  1.0.5
@kext.CoreTrust 1
|IOTimeSync!F   840.3
|IONetworking!F 3.4
|IOReport!F 47
>!AACPIPlatform 6.1
>!ASMC  3.1.9
>watchdog   1
|IOPCI!F    2.9
|IOACPI!F   1.4
@kec.pthread    1
@kec.corecrypto 1.0
@kec.Libm   1
```

Comment: With this, you also had VirtualBox and Photos going.  According to this, Photos was the process associated with the thread that crashed.  Was this a one time thing or is this happening all the time?

Comment: @Allan it was a one time (first time ever, actually) thing

Comment: These things happen.  Page faults are memory errors.  Don't worry about it unless it becomes a recurring thing. A one off doesn't mean your hardware is failing.

Comment: Thank you! Just another question, how is it possible that virtual box was running if I uninstalled this app about two months ago?

Comment: Did you use the uninstaller script that came with it or did you just drag it to the trash?

Comment: @Allan I dragged it to the trash, I see that’s no good. Is there any way I can completely remove it now?

Comment: Reinstall it, so the uninstaller gets installed, then run the uninstaller.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Kernel Panics are usually hardware issues, and you did the right thing by running the hardware diagnostics. Sometimes the hardware issues are intermittent and not caught by hardware diagnostics, and in these cases you have to wait for a pattern to appear out of multiple panics.

The other source of Kernel Panics, though, is the kernel software, including Kernel Extensions, which have names ending with `.kext`. In your case, you have VirtualBox installed, which has installed multiple Kernel Extensions. This is perfectly reasonable, but VirtualBox is free software and [has been known to cause Kernel Panics in](https://www.virtualbox.org/ticket/19018) the past. (Free software, being free, is usually not as rigorously tested or as quickly fixed as commercial software, and often does not have as much official support from Apple, so is more likely to be the source of a Kernel Panic than commercial software like VMware Fusion.)

Uninstall it using the Uninstaller as [explained in the VirtualBox manual](https://www.virtualbox.org/manual/UserManual.html#install-mac-uninstall). Simply moving the application to the trash will not remove the Kernel Extensions.

Then wait and see if your computer panics again.  If it does, keep a copy of the panic and build up a history so you can look for patterns. Probably, though, it will not panic again for a long time.